# sass question. transition of transform effect not applied

Tags: sass, transform, transition

Can someone help me why transition doesn't get applied?

html

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__faces">
    <div class="box__faces--front">
      FRONT
    </div>
    <div class="box__faces--back">
      BACK
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

sass

```
.box
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;

  &__faces
  {
    transition: all 0.8s ease;    // this doesn't seem to be applied.

    &--front
    {
      width:150px;
      height:150px;
      background: blue;
    }

    &--back
    {
      width:150px;
      height:150px;
      background: red;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
  }

  &__faces:hover &__faces--front
  {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  &__faces:hover &__faces--back
  {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

I have a working codepen here:
https://codepen.io/loganlee/pen/RwNJPdZ?editors=1100

I expect rotateY transform for both .box__faces--front and .box__faces--back to be transitioned and I placed transition on the parent element which in this case is .box__faces.

```
transition: all 0.8s ease;    // this doesn't seem to be applied.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `transition` on `.box__faces` class when you need to specify it on the `&--front` and `&--back` classes.

```
.box
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;

  &__faces
  {

    &--front
    {
      width:150px;
      height:150px;
      background: blue;
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
    }

    &--back
    {
      width:150px;
      height:150px;
      background: red;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
    }
  }

  &__faces:hover &__faces--front
  {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  &__faces:hover &__faces--back
  {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```